# Possible Contradiction in N87 ferrite material μa vs B graph

Tags: ferrite, flux, graph

Why does this graph description (of N87 material) states ^B =< 0.25mT (which is peak flux density), even though horizontal axis goes up to 0.40T?

Is the horizontal axis in tesla peak-to-peak? Is it a mistake?

The dοcument is [here](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/download/528882/71e02c7b9384de1331b3f625ce4b2123/pdf-n97.pdf).

[image: μa vs B graph of N87 material]

Comment: The roofed B is the AC probe field that is needed for the AC susceptibility measurement. You don't need to worry about it. it merely details how the curve was produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The caret ^ over the B indicates this is the Peak  magnetic flux density for the small AC value** during a large sweep at a lower frequency.  This is the preferred AC value to measure the slope of the curve.

This is like small signal AC gain vs DC gain.

Many magnetics are rated for current when the inductance drops 10%.  These plots here show the peak AC flux on an otherwise low f sweep or DC flux.

When the curve goes negative, losses and temp increase into possible thermal runaway.  The peak B must be avoided with some safety margin.

Comment: TY. You are probably referring to core saturation that leads to reduction in L, which in turn leads to greater di/dt.. My question was not why ^B<0.25T, but why the graph has values above that.

Answer (score 1):

Amplitude permeability is measured by applying a periodic magnetic field.  The average value of this applied field is theoretically zero when this measurement is made, so that in theory the average flux density would also be zero.  In your case the amplitude permeability curve is specified for the conditions of average (DC) flux density less than 0.25 mT at a frequency of less than 10 kHz.  The amplitude permeability is then calculated from the peak values of the B and H fields.

Comment: TY, @John Birckhead. At https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/download/528882/71e02c7b9384de1331b3f625ce4b2123/pdf-n97.pdf, page 8, "Symbols and Terms", it seems there is a symbol "Bdc" for the DC value, which is different than "^B". So if what you are stating it true, the graph should have read "Bdc<0.25T".

Comment: almost!  Bdc is <0.4 T ...  ^Bac  < 0.25 mT is valid and correct. (never doubt TDK)